# Update InputText in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to disable & delete all texts in 2 certain inputtext fields (`A1`, `A2`), if some fields (`B1`, `B2`) have value:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def gen_layout() -> list:
    layout=[
    [sg.Text('A1', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(key='-INPUT-A1-', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Text('A2', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(key='-INPUT-A2-', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Text('B1', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(key='-INPUT-B1-', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Text('B2', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(key='-INPUT-B2-', enable_events=True)],
    ]
    return layout

def main():
    """ Main function
    """

    # Theme color
    sg.theme('BlueMono')

    # Layout
    layout = gen_layout()

    # Create the window
    window = sg.Window(title="Test", layout=layout, resizable=True)

    # Create an event loop
    while True:
        # Read window
        window_read = window.read()
        if window_read is None:
            break
        event, values = window_read

        # Window closed
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        print(values)

        if (values['-INPUT-B1-'] != "" or values['-INPUT-B2-'] != "") and ('-INPUT-B1-' in event or '-INPUT-B2-' in event):
            # Disable
            window['-INPUT-A1-'].update(disabled=True)
            window['-INPUT-A2-'].update(disabled=True)
            # Delete text
            window['-INPUT-A1-'].update("")
            window['-INPUT-A2-'].update("")
        elif (values['-INPUT-B1-'] == "" and values['-INPUT-B2-'] == "") and ('-INPUT-B1-' in event or '-INPUT-B2-' in event):
            # Enable
            window['-INPUT-A1-'].update(disabled=False)
            window['-INPUT-A2-'].update(disabled=False)

    window.close()

main()
```

The code above **appears to** work (i.e., GUI part is working correctly), but as you can see from `print(values)`: if I input `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` to `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2` respectively, I hope the `values` printouts should be:

```
{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '', '-INPUT-B1-': '', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}
{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '2', '-INPUT-B1-': '', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}
{'-INPUT-A1-': '', '-INPUT-A2-': '', '-INPUT-B1-': '3', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}
{'-INPUT-A1-': '', '-INPUT-A2-': '', '-INPUT-B1-': '3', '-INPUT-B2-': '4'}
```

However, in fact, it is:

```
{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '', '-INPUT-B1-': '', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}
{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '2', '-INPUT-B1-': '', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}
{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '2', '-INPUT-B1-': '3', '-INPUT-B2-': ''} <-- notice this
{'-INPUT-A1-': '', '-INPUT-A2-': '', '-INPUT-B1-': '3', '-INPUT-B2-': '4'}
```

Why is this program working like this? Is there something wrong with my `.update("")` function?

Comment: When you pressed `3`, the `values` is `{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '2', '-INPUT-B1-': '3', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}`, even after you clear the content of `A1` and `A2` because this variable `values` not updated. It will be updated after next event, like after `4` pressed.

Comment: @JasonYang Thank you for the reply! Is there any way to make `values` update automatically after clearing content of `A1` and `A2`, without some manual input as the next event?

Comment: Oh NVM, I figured it out. It should be `window.write_event_value(key, value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments:

> When you pressed `3`, the values is `{'-INPUT-A1-': '1', '-INPUT-A2-': '2', '-INPUT-B1-': '3', '-INPUT-B2-': ''}`, even after you clear the content of `A1` and `A2` because this variable values not updated. It will be updated after next event, like after `4` pressed.

Therefore, we need to trigger an event after deletion, as an example:

```
# Delete text
window['-INPUT-A1-']("")
window.write_event_value('-INPUT-A1-', "")
window['-INPUT-A2-']("")
window.write_event_value('-INPUT-A2-', "")
```

---

Or simply: `values.update({'-INPUT-A1-':"", "'-INPUT-A2-', ""})`

Comment: If you need the dictionary `values` later, just update it by `values.update({'-INPUT-A1-':"", "'-INPUT-A2-', ""}). The method `window.write_event_value`, most of time, it adds a key & value tuple to the queue that is used by threads to communicate with the window.